# MobileConnect AMPSCript not working properly

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect, sms

We have two Data extensions, one contains the information about the contacts to which we need to send the SMS(User_Information) and other contains the Date and the SMS content(SMSContentInfo).At runtime, we are trying to lookup from the SMSContentInfo data extension and get the SMS content which we need to send to the user according to the current date.Here is our AMP script code:

```
%%[
var @curDate,@smscontent
Set @curDate= Now()
Set @smscontent = Lookup("SMSContentInfo","sms_content","report_date",@curDate)
]%%Hey there,todays date: %%[ if not empty(@curDate) then ]%%%%= v(@curDate) =%%%%[ else ]%%current date is empty.Also,sms content is: %%[ if not empty(@smscontent) then ]%%%%= v(@smscontent) =%%%%[ else ]%%sms content is also empty.
```

We do not see any error when we send the SMS, but any SMS which contains the AMP script code , user is not receiving it. Do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the community!
You must close IF condition with [ENDIF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm) statement.

```
Hey there,todays date: 
%%[ if not empty(@curDate) then ]%%
%%= v(@curDate) =%%%
%[ else ]%%
current date is empty.Also,sms content is:
%%[ 
ENDIF
if not empty(@smscontent) then ]%%
%%= v(@smscontent) =%%
%%[ else ]%%
sms content is also empty.
%%[ENDIF]%%
```